# SpringBoot Project occured exception when it has deployed to the server

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a SpringBoot Project in development enviroment which is Windows 7 64 & JDK 8  everything is fine,because I have debuged it,everything just runs fine.when I have packaged it as WAR package to the productive enviroment which is Tomcat 8 & JDK 8  in a Linux Machine,it doesn't work  ,due to I'm not very familar with Java,would you please take a look at what I have done wrong.
I have checked log file,here is some error

```
2016-10-23 16:57:02.314  INFO 8408 --- [localhost-startStop-2]  
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/gjbuploadnew],
methods=[POST],consumes=[application/json;charset=UTF-8],
produces=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public  
com.newwebservice.models.Gjret
com.newwebservice.web.api.UploadgjbnewController.
uploadgjbnew(com.newwebservice.models.Gjupload) 
throws java.sql.SQLException,java.lang.ClassNotFoundException


2016-10-23 16:57:02.318  INFO 8408 ---
[localhost-startStop-2]   
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped 
"{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public
org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndVieworg.
springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml

(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2016-10-23 16:57:02.319  
INFO 8408 --- [localhost-startStop-2]  
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 
Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public 
org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map
<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>>  
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.
error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
```

I did use the jtds library,Although it shows occured the SQL exception in log file,however I found the library which is the jtds-1.3.1.jar file is in webapps/newwebservice/WEB-INF/lib folder,I can't figure out what I have done wrong.

here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"     
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0       
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.newwebservice</groupId>
<artifactId>newwebservice</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>newwebservice</name>
<description>newwebservice</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: There is no error... Only INFO messages. Post your application class and the actual error (if any).

Comment: it occured WinHttpSendRequest: 12002 timeout error in Client-side,I don't know what has happended,the log file seems didn't report error,it's weird that  in developmemt enviroment,everything is fine.

Comment: try to run mvn clean and then repack to war againg. It might fix that issue, because Log seems OK